# Why does Hash.try_convert not convert a two-dimensional array into a Hash?

Tags: ruby

[The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-c-try_convert) say the following for Hash.try_convert(obj):

*Try to convert obj into a hash, using #to_hash method. Returns converted hash or nil if obj cannot be converted for any reason.*

However, when I try this with:

```
[[:a,"a"],[:b,"b"]]
```

I get this:

```
Hash.try_convert([[:a,2],[:b, 3]])
=> nil
```

but if I just use the #to_h method on the array, I get what I consider to be the correct behaviour:

```
[[:a,"a"],[:b,"b"]].to_h
=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}
```

Does this mean that my understanding of the docs is incorrect (i.e. the two approaches above should not be considered analogous), is something else going on, or am I just being dumb in a way I have not considered yet?

Comment: `Hash.try_convert` tries to call `.to_hash` on the given object, not `.to_h`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Arie Shaw in the comments who drew attention to the precise way I was being dumb.

I've subsequently discovered a [related bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10180#change-48525):

*The class Hash has a method try_convert, that is documented as "Try to convert obj into a hash, using #to_hash method." Surpisingly, the Array class doesn't have a method to_hash, but it does have a method to_h which converts it into a Hash. This looks like there are two possible methods with different names, but with the same expected behaviour, which breaks some usage of Hash#try_convert.*

Which was rejected thus:

*Ruby often has two conversion methods for an object, e.g. #to_s and #to_str, #to_i and #to_int, #to_h and #to_hash.
The former is used for explicit conversion, the latter is used for implicit conversion (from an object with identical method signature e.g. proxy).*

And which provides me with the somewhat obvious answer - Array has a #to_h method but not a #to_hash method.